# Specifying Struts templates source

Tags: templates, struts2, freemarker

Say I'm using a form with a text-field.

<@s.form action="login">
        <@s.textfield label="E-mail" name="email"/>
        <@s.submit value="send"/>

How can I specify that the text-form should be generated by a custom template (text_login.ftl) rather than the standard text.ftl?

Answer (score 0):

I did it few years ago, and as I remember I did the following
1) created my own template in forlder

```
src/template/_theme_/_template_.ftl
```

*theme* - it is name of theme used in struts tag definition (see below). E.g. ajax (already defined and existed in Struts2 theme)
*template* - name of your template. E.g. inline-submit:

```
src/template/ajax/inline-submit.ftl
```

2) now in jsp, when I want to show that some tag should use that template, I wrote the following:

```
<s:submit theme="ajax" template="submit-inline" ... />
```

that's all.
In your case you need to write something like that:

```
<@s.textfield label="E-mail" name="email" theme="_DEFINE_WHERE_TEMPLATE_IS_LOCATED" template="text_login"/>
```